# Did the word "to guess" have a brave tone in this context?

Tags: expressions

I had a strange situation today. On another SE website, I found the following comment:

> I'm not asking what is your guess about implementation. I'm asking you
>   what exactly one should be able to do with this dialog. So far I know it
>   should pop up and look similarly. I can guess it should affect Graphics3D
>   somehow, via context menu maybe, but I don't want to guess because we aren't
>   here **to guess** what OPs need.

Source: [Something like ViewPoint Selector (Mathematica.SE)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151346/something-like-viewpoint-selector#comment403830_151346)

I'm Brazilian and I do not know if what was written had a brave tone.

The translation of the word "guess" seemed pejorative to me.

For me phrases such as:

> - I suppose...
> - I think...
> - I imagine...

seem kinder.

I am wrong? Or did the tone have this characteristic?

I was not offended. But I just want to learn if there is a word more appropriate to not generate doubts.

Comment: My bravado meter is reading zero; I don't find anything pejorative about the "to guess" in that comment. But I've upvoted your question because I think it's a fair question and you've done a good job presenting it.

Comment: I thank you. I already have difficulty writing simple things on the sites in the English language and now asking this question really demanded me some care to be clear.

Comment: This my question has almost become an off-topic?

Comment: @LMS The initial letters of my name are very similar to yours. My name is: Leandro Maciel de Carvalho. It's just a silly comment

Comment: LCarvalho - Off-topic? I don't think so. It's a valid question – one that native speakers and learners might find interesting.

Comment: @J.R. How cool !!! There are several nuances in the translation of the Portuguese language into English. For small details, I still misread certain phrases. Including comments. Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"To guess"**, especially in technical circumstances, is a mild pejorative aimed at people who are offering advice or answers based on assumption due to lack of details.

This is quite common in IT/software forums where exact answers are a reasonable possibility.  I am guilty of this myself because presumptive answers cause a lot of unhelpful noise.

Instead of *brave*, I would say "we aren't here to guess" takes an *assertive* tone.

Admittedly guessing is not always a bad thing though:

> **Mr. Spock:** Mr. Scott cannot give me exact figures, Admiral, so... I will make a guess.
>
> **Adm. Kirk:** A guess? You, Spock? That's extraordinary.

Comment: To use a Star Trek series dialogue was amazing.

Comment: I think you understood my feeling. In this type of context can occur much of these things.